# I want to send dictionary contents from server side to client side

Tags: python, client-server

So, in my server side, I created a dict that takes records from a .txt file:

```py
records = {}
with open("data.txt") as f:
for line in f:
    (name1, age, location, number) = line.split("|")
    records[str(name1)] = [age, location, number]
```

As of now, I am able to print this DB on the server side :

```py
print("** Python DB contents **\n")

for keys in records.keys():
     value_list = records[keys]
     print(keys + "|" + value_list[0] + "|" + value_list[1] + "|" + value_list[2])
```

However, I want to send this to the client side, but nothing is working for me.

I have tried sending it to the client side by creating a list that contains the contents, then sending it to the client like so:

Server:

```py
for keys in records.keys():
     value_list = records[keys]   
     string = keys + "|" + value_list[0] + "|" + value_list[1] + "|" + value_list[2]
     client.send(string.encode())
```

Client:

```py
buffer = server.recv(1024).decode() # receive from server 
print(f"Server: {buffer}") # print in server what was sent
```

Anyone know what exactly is wrong here? This is how I've been sending and receiving stuff my whole code but in this case it just does not work!

Comment: Yes, what is wrong here? Does your client print anything?

Comment: @quamrana Nope! That's why I am so confused

Comment: So what is your `client` variable that you expect it to send text from the server to the client?

Comment: @quamrana It is basically like writing `conn.send(...)`, it is the connection

Comment: So really the issue is not yet how a `dict` from server to client, but whether *anything* can be sent. You should use a proxy for now, ie just call `client.send("dict")` to see if the client shows that. Then send the actual `dict`. But beware: what if `records` is empty!

Comment: @quamrana You are right, I could not even send a simple string because of an issue with .recv in the server side. The server was receiving something not even sent from the client. Thanks :]